# HELP! Work Ubuntu Stick is not allowing settings changes to save! then freezes

Tags: nvidia, usb, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, settings

**Issue:
Ubuntu not saving display settings and random glitches happening after trying. Also causing display glitches within AWS.**

DETAILS

I need Some help, I work from home now and my Work Has provided us with Ubuntu sticks to load from Bios and then from there to access Amazon Workspace.
We have been using this method for at least a year now and last week I started having issues.

[Normal Day]
when I load into Ubuntu, I have to access setting since it sets my screen at impossibly high resolution and has all my screens in the wrong positions. I also have to set volume to max, make sure it can hear my headset, set mic input to max and then save.
after hitting 'save' a prompt appears asking would you like to save these changes 'yes' or 'no', and then a small count down. I always click yes and go about my day and then it works fine.
I do this EVERY MORNING at 5:30 am to load into AWS and be at work and have everything ready at the start of my 6am start time.
UNTIL LAST WEEK

[New Issue]
Now when I load into Ubuntu, I access the settings, correctly setting the impossibly high resolution to the correct resolutions so I can read the screen and change placement of monitors so they are in the correct order. (there are 3 monitors)
I go to click the little green button that says SAVE.
The preview Shows everything correctly, and then it all turns black and it reverts back.
It never shows the window that asks if you would like to keep these settings!!!
the confirmation window is completely missing.
when it reverts back it is often distorted, and the mouse curser can move but not click or interact with anything! and the whole thing freezes!!!!! I have to go under the desk and do a hard reset every time.

I tried ignoring it and using aws anyway without adjusting the settings and it just caused more random errors, like programs not responding, my mouse not working on one half of the screen but working on the right half. I couldn't hear anything with the volume so low and cm could not hear my mic at all! its Impossible to get anything done.

please if there is any way to fix this let me know. I really just want to get back to work. I cant afford to loose any more work. I've already lost over a week of shifts because of this.

My IT team has Not really been able to provide a solution as this has not happened to any other users thus far. all they can tell me is they possibly blame it on my pc being made from parts meant for gaming computers, such as the graphics card. I asked them to go into more detail but they refused, leaving me very confused.

(I have a second computer that is a laptop and tried to load the ubunto stick on that, but it was not compatible due to windows 11. so now IT wants me to change my base os from windows 11 to windows 10 on my Gaming laptop with no guarantee that it would work, instead of fixing the actual issue. I have no idea how to do that and it would void all warranties and protection plans that I have on my brand new Helios predictor 300 w/i7 and 2T. so obviously I would like to fix my main tower work pc not destroy my brand new laptop)

PS I was told that new version that we are now using was released while I was on vacation.  and this issue started happening when I received that update.
also I have done a TON of ubunto rebuilds and its not helping.

do I need different hardware????? Please help!!!! I miss work!

Comment: Please realize that not all people do have the time and inclination to read long stories. Edit your question and shorten it substantially. Indicate the specific problem first, then eventually elaborate providing specific details that may contribute in helping the question.

Comment: What graphics card do you have in your tower PC? Have you got an alternative or basic graphics in the processor?

Comment: Geforce GTX, came with the pc dell optiplex 3010. and no onboard graphics just the card.

Comment: @ vanadium sorry for it being too long, I was not sure what information would be helpful as this is not my field of expertise so I was trying to provide as much relevant information as possible in hopes that it might help. I will work on making the next post Shorter next time. thank you for taking the time to read it

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; what do you mean by Ubuntu Stick?  Is this a *live* Ubuntu system you're using?  If so what product/release details?  If *live* are you using *persistence*?

Comment: unfortunately I dont know what that means so I dont know how to answer. what I use is a USB stick that has Ubunto on it provided to me by work. do you know where I could look to get you that information?

Comment: I did find this under info in the flash drive: Ubuntu 18.04.2 2021.11.16 "Custom" (20211116)

Comment: Can you borrow a laptop from a friend and see if the stick works. If it does the issue is a component in your tower. If you have the same problem it’s an issue with the stick. Can your IT people tell you what upgrade they did? Potentially they could revert it

Comment: How did the IT people update a USB drive in your possession when you were on vacation? How/why are you rebuilding something provided to you by IT? Frankly this doesn't make sense.